# Space of ergodic measures is $G_\delta$ in space of invariant measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

I'm reading an old paper by Varadarajan (1963) titled "Groups of automorphisms of Borel spaces" and I'm trying to fulfill the details.
There are many questions I thought about for quite a long time with no success.
For the moment, I confine myself to the first part of the proof of Theorem 4.2 (possibly, the remaining one would be treated in another question).

**Notation and Terminology:**
Suppose $G$ lcsc (=locally compact second countable) group.
By measure we mean a Borel probability measure.
A measure on a Borel space $X$ is said to be invariant if $\mu(A)=\mu(gA)$ for all borel subsets $A$ and $g\in G$ and we write $\mu\in\mathscr{I}$.
It is ergodic if all $G$-invariant Borel subsets are either null or conull.
The set of ergodic measures is denoted by $\mathscr{E}$.

**Q:**
Suppose $Y$ is a compact metric $G$-space ($G$ acts continuously on $Y$), so that the space $\mathscr{I}_Y$ of $G$-invariant measures on $Y$ is compact wrt the weak-topology (the one which makes continuous the functions $\mu\mapsto \int_Y g\,d\mu$ forall bounded continuous real-valyued functions $g\in C_b(Y)$).
Then, referring to a paper by Choquet titled "Existence et unicité des représentations intégrales", he claims $\mathscr{E}_Y$ is a $G_\delta$ subset.
Unfortunately, I have not found such a paper, so I would like to know how to prove that $\mathscr{E}_Y$ is $G_\delta$ (any useful reference on the subject is appreciated, even better if a book).

**Edit:**
I have made the notion of ergodicity more explicit.

Comment: If $\mu$ is invariant by this definition then so is $\lambda \mu$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ so that your set of invariant measures doesn't have extreme points. Most likely you want to restrict to probability measures?

Comment: Oh, yes. I've forgotten to point out this further assumption (Varadarajan calls meaures all the Borel probability measures)

Comment: Theorem  $2.1$ in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255631586) is similar to the result you want (though for them ergodicity is with respect to a single operator and not the action of a group). I haven't checked this so don't know if it is correct but maybe the idea of their proof can be adapted?

Comment: @RhysSteele Thank you for the reference. As you pointed out, maybe there is a way to adapt the argument used there, but I was not able to find it up to now.

Comment: You can find the paper at http://www.numdam.org/article/SB_1956-1958__4__33_0.pdf. See page 39 for the proof.

Comment: @JohnB, thank you for the reference. Now I try to translate the relevant part of the paper and hope to solve the question.